# How to find a Discord Channel using javascript StartsWith

Tags: javascript, discord.js

What I want to do is if a channel was created with a name (for example, `ticket-`), it will send a message to that channel.

This is what I have:

```
client.on('channelCreate', (bot, channel) => {
    const guild = (`721301561963446324`);
    if (message.channel.name.startsWith('ticket-')) {
        try {
            guild.channel.send(`test`)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
  });
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to send `test` in a channel when it's created, if its name starts with `ticket-`. If so, your code is too complicated, it's easier

```js
client.on('channelCreate', (channel) => {
    if(channel.name.startsWith('ticket-')){
        channel.send('test');
    }
});
```